# Save information to database after jquery callback

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I'm new here and I'm very new at programming but I need some serious hand-by-hand help here.

I was searching jquery and found a script to drag and drop stuff on the screen, basicly i just want to move some divs around, thats the easy part, the script I found has a callback function that writes onto the div that you just moved "dropped", this is exactly what I need but instead of writting dropped I want to save the 2 postion variables into a database (mysql), this is so that if I close the browser and open it again the div's will be on the last place I dropped them.

Can you help? Is there a jquery user interface with this already built in ?

I think this is easy to do with jquery ajax functions right? basicly I should send the serialized data (json right?) into a page that processes that data once its feed into it, then jason returns the handler with success or even with some output right?

It would be cool for the dragabble div to have a handler with last know position retrieve by jason from an external page that acts like a buffer to the database.

Is this the correct pipeline?

Best Regards
Joricam

Comment: Have you tried something? You should do that right? I think you didn't tried anything, right? Am I wrong? right? It seems like if you want us to write code for you, right?

Answer (score 1):

you have kind of a vague question here, but I can try to help you get closer to the answer.

Imagine two sides of the puzzle:

1. When the page loads, the two (or more) DIVs are drawn on the screen. If you want them to draw in a specific order, you need to keep track of that in the database. So be sure your db has a field called something like `display_order`, and then display the DIVs in that order. (You can usually just add `ORDER BY display_order` to the SQL, so they are retrieved in the order you want, and then draw the DIVs right out in a loop.)
2. When someone drags and drops a DIV, you use AJAX/JSON/etc to tell your PHP script the new order. In this case, when that happens, rather than draw the word 'dropped' in the DIV, you should instead immediately update the `display_order` fields in the database. This way you are remembering each DIV's position.

Does that help/make sense?

**UPDATED:** thinking more about your question, here is the pseudo code:

in "display.php":

- Fetch the contents for each DIV from the database, with `ORDER BY display_order` on the rows.
- Draw them on the screen, looping through each database row.
- Also in this HTML, use the jQuery script you already have to call another PHP script (dragged.php) when a row is dragged.

in "dragged.php":

- This script is called when a row is dragged on the screen.
- Currently it puts the word "dropped" in the DIV that is dragged. That's not helpful, so remove that.
- Instead, you now know (from the variables passed to you) that a specific DIV needs to be in a specific place.
- So grab a list of the DIVs from the database, then change the order of them (by altering the `display_order` column) based on the new position(s) you know.
- Save that back to the database, so when display.php is called again next time, it draws the DIVs in the order you want.

Hope this helps explain further. If you are still struggling, I respectfully suggest you try to write the code, and post a more specific question about the part that you're stuck on. This will help you get a good answer quickly. (You may also want to Google this one a lot; I'm sure there are code samples out there showing how to do all this.)

Comment: not  really :\, because my idea is not about the order of the divs but to position them trough css, so I need the last position of the div.

What i wan to achieve is sort of having a canvas on the webpage where i move images around that ar wraped in a div with a handler, then if I close the page and open it again the images will be in the last place i dragged them, can you help please?

Comment: Hmm -- your original question said "I want to save the 2 postion variables into a database (mysql), this is so that if I close the browser and open it again the div's will be on the last place I dropped them." -- so that's what I answered. If you already have the drag and drop code in place, then you have the hard part done. I'm not sure how else I can help. Maybe post a new question and be very specific? Or post some (simplified) code showing what you already have done?

Comment: I've updated my answer to help a bit. If you haven't already, try writing some code and see if you can sort it out. It sounds like you already have part of it working.